# Adjust accept-encoding preference inside Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, http-headers

I'm trying to test how my application will respond when different sorts of accept-encoding headers are sent by the browser in the request. Firefox's about:config allows me to customize these values, but after several Google searches, I'm unable to find how to do the same in Internet Explorer 8.

Any ideas?